# OR Condition in Scope Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `prescription.rb` model, I have written the following working `scope`
Note that: `prescription has_many patient_prescriptions`

```
scope :undeleted_prescriptions, -> { includes(:patient_prescriptions).where(patient_prescriptions: { is_deleted: false })}
```

Now I want it to return also those records where is_deleted: nil e.g. 
all record **where is_deleted is false or nil**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :undeleted_prescriptions, -> { includes(:patient_prescriptions).where(patient_prescriptions: { is_deleted: [false,nil] })}
```